# Fixed Positioning With Scrolling

Tags: css

If, for example, I have a menu using fixed positioning but it's larger than the height of the current window, is there a way to allow this to scroll?  The browser's default behaviour is to just hide it, and not let you access it.

```
div#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    top:30px;
    left:0;
    bottom:4px;
    width:148px;
    background-color:#d7d7d7;
}
```

Here's a snippet of what I've currently got.  Would it require some JavaScript or something along those lines?

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if this is actually possible to get correct.  I want an element which is 30 pixels from the top of the document.  I want to allow this to scroll using overflow:auto and height:100%.  Either way I seem to do it, the scrollbar will be hidden, or a portion of the div will be hidden.

Comment: You've accepted an answer, therefore people will assume it works.

Comment: In relation to the question, the answer is correct, but in relation to the context, it's not perfect.  I'm fully aware of this, but just because a question has been marked as answered, it does not indicate that the discussion has finished, otherwise a question would close once answered.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'll need to set `overflow:scroll` (or `overflow:auto`) to that div, and set height to 100%.

Comment: That'd work fine, however with top:30px set the scrollbars won't display correctly.  Would I have to contain this div within another div.  Have fixed position on the outer div and something else on the inner div?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Set an inner div with your content, set the outer div with padding-top: 30px and get rid of top: 30px :)

Comment: In cases where you can't set `height: 100%` (expanding navigation bars on mobile for example), you can simply use `max-height: 100%`